# Spring call controller action from jsp by <a> tag

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm a newbie Spring MVC, I can't call controller from jsp by tag `<a>`. I try a lots but don't know why. When I click the link, the server announced error 404.  Please help me !

My controller

```
       @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/form",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public class formController {
        @RequestMapping(value="/registry", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String registry (ModelMap mm){
            mm.addAttribute("user",new user());
            return "registry";
        }

    @RequestMapping(value="/regProccess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String regProccess(@ModelAttribute(value="user") user user,ModelMap mm){
        mm.put("user",user);
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

My jsp

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/form/registry">Registry</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

dispatcher-servlet

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />
<bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

Comment: can you show your web.xml servlet mapping for spring?

Comment: what will be the value for <%= request.getContextPath()%> ? You are specifying the request URL as /for/registry and trying to access this URL by <%= request.getContextPath()%>/form/registry .

Comment: Do you have a jsp named "registry.jsp" in `WEB-INF/jsp`? Any log?